# Python code to print out value in any variable

Tags: python

What are some good ways to "pretty print" values of any variable (and anything inside the variable), whether it is:

- scalar
- object
- list of scalar or objects
- dict of scalar or objects
- tuple of scalar or objects

Thanks

Comment: what's so ugly about `print`?

Comment: You're hosed on the last 4 if the object doesn't implement a "pretty" `__str__` or `__repr__` method. Otherwise use the `pprint` module.

Comment: "best code" always imply opinion-based, more or less. Also, "best" code will depend on what you want to print (e.g. if you want to print list of custom objects without `__repr__` there is little you can do out of the box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on top of Aeiddius's answer.

This works well on natives types like scalar, lists of scalars, and dicts of scalars:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(var)
```

But for user-defined objects, I got things like `<MyClass object at 0x10fcf93d0>`

Below works well on user-defined objects:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(vars(object))
```

There doesn't seem to be one simple solution that works for all cases on this need.

Answer (score 2):

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(var)
```

And if you don't like `pprint`, try https://pypi.org/project/pprintpp/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on object. I got like `<MyClass object at 0x10fcf93d0>`